# Hadoop Cascading framework to Update specific column data

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I have a `mongodb` collection  which looks like this

```
Id  Name    createTime  updateTime  Age Country verificationStatus
Id1 Abc 10-7-2013   10-7-2013   21  Xxxx    INITIAL_MAIL
Id2 Efg 9-7-2013    10-7-2013   22  Xxxx    FIRST_REMINDER
Id3 Hij 8-7-2013    10-7-2013   45  Xxxx    INITIAL_MAIL
```

I have a cascading job which does some evaluation from another collection and I want to update just “`verificationStatus`” and “`updateTime`” columns by “`Id`” without disturbing the other columns

But in cascading if I set these two columns I am losing the other column data. I am left with something like this.

```
Id  updateTime  verificationStatus
Id1 11-7-2013   BLOCKED
Id2 11-7-2013   SECOND_REMINDER
Id3 11-7-2013   FIRST_REMINDER
```

`SinkMode UPDATE` works well for updating transaction by transaction but not individual column data.

How can I approach this issue?

PS:  Join or  Merge doesn’t work. Since Source and Sink cannot point to the same collection by casacading design.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Write a cascading `Function` that updates these two columns above and pass in the `Function` and the original fields into a `Pipe` and use `Fields.REPLACE` to replace the columns with the new column values.

**Option 2:**

You could create two `Pipes` one with the original column data that you want to keep that includes the `id` field you mention in your post and another `Pipe` that updates those columns and then use a `CoGroup` to bring these datasets back together.